# Is there a way to add values to a dictionary without overwriting the existing value

Tags: python

So I am reading from a text file and creating a dictionary (my_dict) such that each word in the file gets a 'key' in the dictionary, and each and every line that the word appears in gets recorded to the corresponding value. I have something working, but the value gets overwritten each time the loop iterates. How do I append values to a dictionary in Python?

```
def inverse_index():
    my_dict = {}
    for count, value in enumerate(open('doc0.txt')):
        for word in value.split():
            print(count, word)
            my_dict[word] = count
    print(my_dict)
```

The input(doc0.txt) such that "/n" is a new line =
A bb Ccc , . "/n"
D ee A bb "/n"
FFF

the output should be
{{'a': [0, 1], 'bb': [0, 1], 'ccc': [0], ',': [0], '.': [0], 'd': [1], 'ee': [1],
'fff': [2]}

Comment: Each key can only exist once. But the value associated with that key could be a list of values, or you could _add_ the count each time (say). It would help to show your data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  this would be a good opportunity to practice providing a complete, minimal example.  I can't run your code because `'doc0.txt'`  is not a file on your system.  Can you write code that exemplifies only the problem in your question ,without external dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR

Instead of

```py
my_dict[word] = count
```

You may want to use

```py
my_dict[word] = my_dict[word] + [count]
```

This is assuming:

- count is the line(s) that the word was found in
- you want each key to have a list of count denoting which lines the word was found on

## Explanation

To assign values to a dict you assign to a specific key in the same way that you might assign a value to an index of a list. You did that in this line here:

```py
# assign value "count" to dict "my_dict" at key "word"
my_dict[word] = count
```

So you're already partway there! What we want now is to add to a preexisting value. Remembering that in Python assignment **replaces** the **value** of a variable, then we want to be careful to assign with our updated value. With int variables we do this by taking the **previous** value and **adding** to it (ex `a = a + 2`), likewise to add to a list in a dict key we take the previous value and assign that plus what was added to it.

**Example**

```py
my_dict = {}                       # {}
my_dict["a"] = [1]                 # {"a": [1]}
my_dict["a"] = my_dict["a"] + [2]  # {"a": [1, 2]}
```

This works because `my_dict["a"]` evaluates to it's current value (a list), and you can then append another list to that list to create a list with the values of both lists. Like

```py
list_a = [1, 2]
list_b = [3, 4]
list_a = list_a + list_b  # == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

### Cool Tip

Since the operation of adding to an existing value is common in Python,  it actually has a shorthand for this pattern.

Instead of

```py
a = a + 2
```

You also have the option to write the shorthand of that which is

```py
a += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want not sure.if word not in dict initiate a empty list. Then append when found.use strip removetrailing characters.

```
def inverse_index():
        my_dict = {}
        with open('doc0.txt','r') as f:
          for count, value in enumerate(f):
            for word in value.strip().split():
               if(word.strip() not in my_dict):
                   my_dict[word.strip()] = []
               print(count, word.strip())              
               my_dict[word.strip()].append(count)
        print(my_dict)
```

Comment: you are referencing 'word' before it is assigned

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: Is this the answer you expected?

Comment: It now runs, but is not giving correct dictionary as result

Comment: 'a' appears in lines 0 and 1 so it should contain [0,1] as the value for the key = 'a'. It is only returning [0]

Comment: What is the output when use the above function?

Comment: {'A': [0], 'bb': [0], 'Ccc': [0], ',': [0], '.': [0], 'D': [1], 'ee': [1], 'FFF': [2]}

Comment: I updated function check whether now it working.

Comment: it has exact same output

Comment: Try adding strip() to value. I updated again.

Comment: Still same output {'A': [0], 'bb': [0], 'Ccc': [0], ',': [0], '.': [0], 'D': [1], 'ee': [1], 'FFF': [2]}

Comment: There was a intendation issue earlier . I fixed it now. Earlier append is inside if condition. Now it should work.